# Supremum and infimum with proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I need to **prove** that the set **$M=\left\{\cfrac{6}{{\left(x-2\right)}^{3}}:\quad x≤0\right\}$** is bounded and find ***inf* M** and ***sup* M**.

The derivative $\cfrac{d}{dx}\cfrac{6}{{\left(x-2\right)}^{3}}=\cfrac{-18\quad}{{\left(x-2\right)}^{4}}≤0$ for all $x≤0$. Therefore $\cfrac{6}{{\left(x-2\right)}^{3}}$ is decreasing for all $x≤0$.

From this, I understand that M will have its highest value when $x=-\infty$ (which is $0$) and its lowest value when $x=0$ (which is $\cfrac{-3}{4}$). Therefore, ***sup* M**$=0$ and ***inf* M**$\cfrac{-3}{4}$.

Now, how do I **prove** this?

Answer (score 1):

- You have that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty }\frac{6}{(x-2)^3}=0\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{6}{(x-2)^3}=\frac{-3}{4}.$$
  and thus the function is bounded, and thus admit an infimum and a supremum.
- Now, the derivative is strictly negative for all $x$, therefore the function has no local extremum on $(-\infty ,0)$. Therefore,
  $$\frac{-3}{4}\leq \frac{6}{(x-2)^3}\leq 0,$$
  and thus $\frac{-3}{4}$ it the infimum and $0$ the supremum.

Comment: @FilipChristiansen:I corrected it, tks,